# Using UIBackgroundModes to run code in background mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Has anyone tried using `UIBackgroundModes` to register for any networking stuff? I want to keep running my server fetching code and playing some sound based on the server response even when my application is in the background or the device is sleeping.

Any clue on this and what would be the impact of using this?

Comment: What does N/W stand for?

Comment: Networking. Basically server calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `UIBackgroundModes` to declare your app is for VoIP and register a periodic keepalive handler, you can do pretty much whatever you want in the background. But you won't make it onto the App Store with that unless you're really a VoIP app. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) for what kind of things are allowed in the background and what aren't.